# Geoserver - Layer creation via data import

Tags: csv, import, excel

We have about 400 sites (materialized by coordinates in the spreadsheet file to be imported) and several fields of information attached to these sites (coordinates, site ID, name, comments, category, etc). This data have been collected during a site survey and now need to be presented on a map, with details shown when a user clicks on the site spot appearing on the map.

Is there any particular workflow that one would recommend to successfully complete this task with Geoserver and avoid a manual entry of all the data already available on a well structured Excel spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

There is an unsupported [excel datastore](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/unsupported/excel) in [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) that can be added to GeoServer to work directly from your spreadsheet. But the easiest answer would be to open the file in [QGIS](http://qgis.org) and save it as a shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 400 sites, I'd recommend converting it to JSON.

Or you could load the CSV directly using a Leaflet plugin like this: https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore

Or if you want to point and click, load it into CartoDB.

Get in touch if you want someone to do it for you =)